# Swift JSON data still not saved after completion?

Tags: json, swift

I've been trying to figure out why my JSON data did not get appended into my global variables. I know that it is because it takes time for my functions to get fetch and process the JSON data. So I've tried to using a completion block to check to see if there's anything in it. However, I still got nothing inside. I am wondering where am I doing it worng?

Here's the code:

```
 @IBAction func dismissButton(_ sender: UIButton) {
    yelpAPIRequest(completion: {
        print("WE are done")
        print(self.businessName)
    })
}



 func yelpAPIRequest(completion:@escaping ()->()){
    let coordinate = YLPCoordinate(latitude: userLatitude , longitude: userLongitude)
    let query = YLPQuery(coordinate: coordinate)
    query.term = "dessert"
    query.limit = 5
    query.radiusFilter = 16094

    YLPClient.authorize(withAppId: clientId, secret: clientSecret).flatMap { client in
        client.search(withQuery: query)
        }.onSuccess { search in
            if search.businesses.isEmpty == false {
                let topBusiness = search.businesses

                for i in topBusiness{
                    print(i.identifier)
                    self.retrieveBusinessFromAPI(id: i.identifier)
                }
                completion()
            } else {
                print("No businesses found")
            }
        }.onFailure { error in
            print("Search errored: \(error)")
    }
}
func retrieveBusinessFromAPI(id: String){
    let url = URL(string: "https://api.yelp.com/v3/businesses/\(id)")
    var request: URLRequest = URLRequest(url: url!)
    request.setValue("Bearer \(apiKey)", forHTTPHeaderField: "Authorization")
    request.httpMethod = "GET"
    let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request, completionHandler: { (data, response, error) in
        let businessData = JSON(data)
        self.businessName.append(businessData["name"].string)
        self.businessYelpURL.append(businessData["url"].string)
        self.businessImageURL.append(businessData["image_url"].string)
        self.businessIsOpenNow.append(businessData["hours"][0]["is_open_now"].bool)
        self.businessPrice.append(businessData["price"].string)
        self.businessRating.append(businessData["rating"].int)
        self.businessAddress.append([businessData["location"]["display_address"].string])
    })
    task.resume()
}
```

EDIT: Yes ive looked at other posts about this same topic but the makority of them all pointed towards the completion: and I've done that but my data is still not saved

Comment: Try using response.data instead

Comment: @UmairAamir I do get the data in my businessData so it's not the problem that I am getting nothing back.

Comment: I didn’t get it. Where are you trying to access your global variables then?

Comment: @UmairAamir at the very top when I taped the button it will print out what's in my businessName array

Comment: Where are you initializing businessNames?

Comment: @UmairAamir it is a global variable declared at the top of the class..

Comment: `dataTask(with` works asynchronously too, so your completion handler is called before the data are returned from the yelp API. You would need to add a completion handler also for `retrieveBusinessFromAPI`.

Comment: @vadian thank you for your reply. I've been trying to plug completion() everywhere and I am not sure where I really should put it. I've put my completion block in the block of dataTask as well as below task.reume() but at best I am only getting 3 items?

Comment: @vadian nvm I found my mistake... I am such an idiot thank you so much for your help!! Please put your answer so I can mark it as the answer